# Geting only alert Output from JS file but not run functionality with available hook "wp_footer" and any other

Tags: jquery, wordpress, hook

**Working Code Status:**

I was testing my js files, what these files were adding and running correctly or not. So I write a alert code in my-custom.js with my theme functionality, and now I hook my jquery file path with in a function. and I hook it by this hook code. `add_action('init', 'run_jquery');`

**My following code work and it displays alert message & also run my functionalists, which are written on my-custom.js file.**

```
 function run_jquery() 
 {
// I used this for assurity of function is running or not.
     echo "<h1>Inside Function</h1>";
        if (!is_admin()) 
        {
// I used this for assurity of condition is working or not.
             echo "<h1>Inside Admin condition</h1>";
            wp_deregister_script('jquery');

            wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js', true, '1.8.1');

            wp_register_script( 'my-custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), true );


            wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

            wp_enqueue_script('my-custom-js');
        }
 }

 add_action('init', 'run_jquery');
```

**Problem Facing:**
**But when I want to hook this function by this way**,  `add_action('wp_enqueue_script', 'run_jquery');` and want to display in footer by this `do_action('wp_enqueue_script');`
it only shows alert message from my-custom.js file, but not echo values inside function run_jquery() and nor run functionality which is in my-custom.js file, while only get alert("hello world") message from my-custom.js file  without going inside function run_jquery(). I did not understand how this piece of code run without going inside of run_jquery() function.